# Recover deleted file that was already overwritten

Tags: macos, data-recovery

I'm using Mac OS Ventura on a system with a 128GB SSD formatted as APFS.

I deleted a PDF from the Trash about a month ago.

I used a trial of EaseUS and it was able to recover the file.
However, I couldn't download as it was trial software.
There was a preview that I kept clicking on. My thoughts were to maybe just screenshot the preview.

Then the preview stopped loading. Wasn't sure if this was a feature limitation or if the file was lost due to me previewing it so many times.

In the midst of this, I also ran a couple of other data recovery software in attempts to be able to download the actual file. PhotoRec was one of them. I ran out of disk space using PhotoRec and then had to clear its results.

Finally, I had to close EaseUS (it gave me warning saying I could lose data due to being overwritten).

PhotoRec and the other software did not result in getting the PDF.

I then tried a non-trial version of EaseUS and unfortunately it did not find the PDF anymore.

I ran it a couple more times and then also tried Disk Drill. No dice.

Is it lost forever or is there some "better software" out there that might be able to find it?

Comment: If care about this file IMMEDIATELY stop using the PC/drive. Then back it up (clonezilla, dd, etc.). Then analyze the backup. Deleted files are eventually overwritten as John mentioned

Comment: I understand your point now. I feel like it's already lost if I cannot find it with software several times. But I get that cloning is the first step to take if there's any salvaging. Something to consider

Comment: Another way (I use this) is to make folders in "Documents":   Stuff A to be deleted, Stuff B to be deleted, ...   I put bank reconciliations, approved documents that I email out. Once a year I go through and delete very old stuff.  If someone (or me) needs something in the past year, I have it

Comment: Just to state the obvious, since nobody else did yet: Restore the file from your backup. If you don't have a regular backup process in place, learn from this mistake and establish one now. That is **much** better use of your time than learning about recovery techniques. You don't even need third party software for that, MacOS has [built-in backup tools](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201250).

Comment: None of this will be helped by the teeny 128GB drive, which most people seem to keep over-full anyway. Any freed-up space will be snapped up by something else in no time at all.

Comment: @gregg How do I analyze the backup?

Comment: "I ran out of disk space using PhotoRec and then had to clear its results." This is the worst possible case. When trying to recover deleted files, one should avoid at all costs to create new files or overwrite/extend existing files, because they might be saved over the block you're trying to recover. @user2402616 a backup is a copy. If you haven't made copies, or configured software to make copies (e.g. Time Machine), then you don't have a backup.

Comment: @user2402616 I don't honestly know how to load the backup easily. Basically you are going to mount the drive as read-only (if possible) or point one of this recovery tools (ex: photorec) to the drive backup file/folder

Comment: @Tetsujin Correct! The original poster should invest in a Time Machine drive just use that to recover files. An overwritten file is an overwritten file and that’s that. Time Machine backups in macOS are a lifesaving safety net that is the best proactive tool anyone using macOS can and should use to recover data. And you say this, “PhotoRec and the other software did not result in getting the PDF.”  But also say this, “I used a trial of EaseUS and it was able to recover the file. However, I couldn't download as it was trial software.” EaseUS  clearly worked. You should have just paid for it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this was just a comedy of errors. Each move the OP did made the recovery less likely, until such a point it became empirically *too late*. Installing new software, repeatedly scanning [the cache files have to go somewhere, overwriting precious data space]. Not using a second drive as recovery location. Had the question been asked earlier, even Time Machine's own local non-configured backup may have held it safe [TM has a small  self-configured safety net even if the user never bothered to set it up properly]. Anyway, OP now knows why we have backups. Better luck next time.

Comment: @Tetsujin "comedy of errors"!  No need to be so harsh. :D:D:D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you might be able to see filenames and sizes that doesn't mean that you will be able to recover any actual data. Filesystem metadata is stored differently in the filesystem from actual file data and is subject to different retention periods and patterns.

The file data may be overwritten already but there is an even bigger problem to recovering data, and that is the fact you are using an SSD.

SSDs have wear levelling algorithms that, at a level below the filesystem the computer uses, rearranges data to make best use of the limited write cycles available on an SSD. The wear levelling isn't necessarily a problem of itself, but one tool available to the computer operating system to  help the wear leveller is: the [TRIM command](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trim_(computing)).

Using TRIM the operating system can tell the SSD what blocks no longer contain data that needs to be retained. A block that once contained data and has had TRIM issued to it is essentially scheduled to be reset to a blank state, either all 1's or 0's depending on the SSD. The actual erase may happen some hours or days later as the SSD controller erases and recycles blocks during idle time.

A block that has had TRIM executed for it may not even return the original data immediately after the command has been run. The SSD controller may recognise the it has been told that the block is blank and therefore it does not need to actually read any real data from the NAND flash. It may well simply return a block of zeroed data.

That said simply emptying the trashcan may or may not immediately make the data unrecoverable as most modern operating systems seem to run TRIM on a schedule, I do not know about MacOS but Windows and Linux typically runs it on a weekly schedule. There is [an answer at Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/411123/389108) that states that MacOS runs TRIM on every boot so if you shut down your machine each night you could have lost the possibility of recovery the very next morning. Alternatively the filesystem is also able to issue a TRIM command directly after every file deletion meaning that it would be unrecoverable after emptying the trash can.

A month is likely to be far too long for any kind of data recovery. If the OS didn't use TRIM then the data likely got overwritten already and is unrecoverable.  If the OS does use TRIM then the data was likely unrecoverable the moment that the operating system told the drive to recycle the data blocks.

The reason that you can still see the filenames and sizes is because, as mentioned, that kind of metadata is handled by the filesystem itself and the list of files in a directory may be kept together. A directory is most easily thought of as a special file that contains a list of other files and that file is most easily handled by simply appending new items to it. When a file is deleted the entry gets marked as "deleted" but the metadata for the file might not be completely removed or overwritten for some time. Changing a byte or two in the directory "file" (to mark as deleted) and writing it back is far faster than reading it in, shuffling the entire block of data around to remove the now deleted files and then writing it back, especially when deleting a lot of files. Lazy editing like this is very common in filesystems when performance is more important and gives the false impression that your data may be recoverable when the actual file data was lost long ago.

Comment: Although Windows indeed maintains a weekly schedule, it also TRIMs immediately after deletion (I tried: https://youtu.be/NyLQbxnPurc) and I think (but not entirely certain) same happens on modern Mac OS.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen fair enough, that makes sense and I was not certain of the behaviour. I just know that some embedded Linux systems disable trim on delete behaviour in favour of a scheduled run "for performance reasons" and considered Windows similar due to it having a scheduled option as well. I'll try to update my answer later if I can find sources on MacOS behaviour.

Answer (score 6):

> I deleted a pdf from the Trash about a month ago.

That is a very long time to leave deleted file remnants on your system. It will have been over-written, likely many times.

There is no hope at this point to recover a month old deleted file.

It is gone.

Comment: There's still a ton of files from around same time period that are still being found. And I did in fact find this pdf once. Just wondering if it got overwritten due to me accessing it several times and/or attempting data recovery multiple times

Comment: The over-writing makes it essentially impossible to  recover,

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it is *probably* lost forever, although I can't guarantee that. The only way to be completely sure would be to exhaustively look through a copy of the drive, cross off everything that is definitely not your PDF and then see if there is anything left.

Note that the more you use the drive the higher the chance of it being overwritten, and it seems you used it a whole lot, installing new software, filling up the whole drive with recovered photos (ergo, overwriting everything that is not a recovered photo), and just leaving the computer turned on for a month with the usual background processes running. Therefore I don't think there is much chance.

---

You've discovered why if you accidentally delete something, you need to immediately turn off the computer (as quickly as possible; pull the plug or hold down the power button rather than shitting it down). This maximizes the chance the file is still there. Remember this for next time.

Then you make a safe copy of the entire drive, onto a file on a bigger drive, so it won't be overwritten. Then make another copy of *that* copy, and you can mess around with the second copy, knowing that anything you do can be undone because the original drive data is still in the first copy. You probably don't know how to do this (especially if the drive isn't removable) but that's okay - take it to a professional - they will probably charge around $100 if it's a simple job.

---

You've also discovered why people recommend doing backups, which is to say, copying all your files onto a separate bigger drive (but a little smarter than that).

Apple has this system called Time Machine which manages it for you; I don't know very much about it. If you had been using Time Machine (which would require you to have another drive, plug it in to your computer periodically and tell it to make a backup), [you could access your old files](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/restore-files-mh11422/mac) using the Time Machine software.

Comment: Actually, Time Machine runs locally all the time, even if you never bothered to set it up properly, for added protection. Within a day [or even up to a week, space allowing] of this deletion, it would have still been safely there. The OP's issue is they just did all the wrong things in all the wrong order, & still thought it would be sitting waiting for them a month later.

Answer (score 1):

> ...I ran out of disk space using PhotoRec...

> Is it lost forever or is there some "better software" out there that might be able to find it?

#### You've lost the file.

That is, if you restored files back onto the device they were deleted on, and ran out of disk space, then you overwrote all your empty space with recovery files.  Anything you failed to recover is hopelessly lost.